# Interface implementation with valid subtype

Tags: c#, roslyn

Is there a reason why a method with a more specific type cannot implement an interface with a less specific one?

```
public interface IInterface<out T>
{
    T GetValues();
}

public class Class : IInterface<object>
{
    public Class GetValuesSubType() => null;

    //public object GetValues() => GetValuesSubType();

    // This won't compile:
    public Class GetValues() => null;
}
```

As the method returning the same values is perfectly valid code with only upcasting.

Is it a by design or is it just a "missing" feature?

EDIT:

It might actually be supported in C#7: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/357

Comment: Yes it breaks [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).  This should be closed as a dupe, I don't have the question that has been already answered on here...

Comment: How is this braking Liskov's principle? "if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S". And it actually compiles and doesn't generate any runtime error if we use a rounting method.

Comment: Because your method `GetValues()` can only return a class (horribly named) `Class`.  Any derived type of `Class` cannot return `object`, only `Class`.

Comment: @ErikPhilips The Wikipedia article you linked to mentions that this ("Covariance of return types in the subtype") is allowed by LST.

Comment: Consider the case where your *sigh* `Class` class has fifty methods, each of which return some type that inherits from `object` (e.g.: all of them), and takes zero parameters in its signature. Which of them is the implementation of `IInterface<T>`?

Comment: @svick Exactly, contravariance in return types is perfectly Liskov compiant... Erik: Feel free to edit the post with a name that tickles your fancies, although absolutely irrelevant.

Comment: I can't find the article, but [Eric Lippert](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/) mentioned that C# does not support Covariance for return types or something (maybe that it never will)...

Comment: @Preston It won't compile in any case if the methods have the same name, even if it's not implementing the inferface, unless I am misunderstanding your answer.

Comment: BTW, you're code isn't *Covariance of return types in the subtype* which would be to `return new Class()` you're actually changing the signature of the interface, but not in the interface, that is the issue.

Comment: @Uno Of course you're right, I wasn't thinking =\

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you declare in interface that you want to return 'object'.
In this case GetValues should return 'object' not Class.

Assume we have Class 
`public class Class : IInterface` with Class as template argument not object as you wanted.

Then IL code looks like this :

```
.method public final hidebysig newslot virtual 
    instance class Namespace.Class GetValues () cil managed
```

We can see "hidebysig" here.
It is translated to "hide by name-and-signature" thus if you would have another signature in IInterface and another in Class as a result you would have no override, just adding new method with the same name but different argument vector - we do not want that.

Also, inherited class would be abstract because of an empty slot for interface's declaration.

Interesting fact : 
As far as I know all methods in C# are hidebysig by definition.

Comment: "But remember that we can not have the same name for two methods with identic arument vector and different return type." Why not? I tried writing such methods IL, and compiling them using ilasm and verifying using peverify and everything was fine.

Comment: I was thinking about creating raw C# code without using dynamic object creation. I deleted this sentence since it was not entirely true - you are absolutely right